# How to activate the click Event in flex?

Tags: events, flex3

```
<mx:StringValidator source="{ host_txt }" property="text" 
            tooShortError="This URI is shorter than the minimum allowed length." 
            minLength="8" trigger="{ connect_btn }" triggerEvent="click"
            valid="setupConnection()"/>
```

How to activate the `click event` for `{ connect_btn }` manually?

Answer (score 0):

In this code when the `connect_btn` clicked it starts validating the text in `host_txt` and if success invokes `setupConnection()` so, as far as i can understand your question you want to do something else when you click the button please correct me if i understand it incorrectly, you do that by giving a value to the click attribute

```
<mx:Button label="button" id="connect_btn" click="yourMethod()"/>
```

hope this is what you want.